# How to get a range of values in Java

Tags: java, generics, range

I'd like to get a range of values like range function in Python.

```
# Python range
a = range(0,1.0,0.01)
b = range(5,10,2)
```

In Java, I hope to get such result as List.

```
// Java range
public class range{

    private double start;
    private double end;
    private double step;

    public range(double start,double end, double step) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.step = step;
    }

    public List<Double> asList(){
        List<Double> ret = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(double i = this.start;i <= this.end; i += this.step){
            ret.add(i);
        }

        return ret;
    }   
}
```

But, I think this code has calculate redundancy when a range of Integer is needed.

Could you have more smarter way or implementation in Java?

Comment: What is "calculate redundancy"?

Comment: Do you need a universal solution for all primitive types, as Python has?

Comment: @muzzlator if I put Integers to the constructor, they will be treated as double. In the calculation of asList, I think the precision of double is not needed. Is this mistake?

Comment: @ilya Yes, I hope to know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a stream to generate the range and collect it to a list

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the first number is inclusive and the second is exclusive. You can use the rangeClosed method to include the second argument.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-

There are other types of streams for other primitives (e.g. see DoubleStream.iterate for example).

Comment: In addition to that, there is [rangeCloses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) method, where both ends are included.

Comment: There are also other stream types for some of the other primitives (see DoubleStream.generate or iterate for example)

Comment: Could you please edit you answer and include all this additional info?

Comment: This is simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is similar method in Java SE 7 ?

Comment: @ric not built in. For Java 7 you'd need to use a 3rd party library like Guava

Answer (score 0):

If you need a possibility to generate numbers of any type, and you are allowed to use third-party libraries, I would recommend to use [Guava Ranges](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained).

Uppermost, `Ranges` are used to manipulate with ranges, as "mathematical abstractions". But you are allowed to generate sequences from ranges:

```
Set<Integer> set = ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, 5), DiscreteDomain.integers());
// set contains [2, 3, 4]
```

By default, Guava supplies you with three kinds of discrete domains: integers, longs and big integers. But you are allowed to create your own:

> You can make your own DiscreteDomain objects, but there are several important aspects of the DiscreteDomain contract that you must remember.

Please, consult [official docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained#discrete-domains) about `DiscreteDomain` implementation peculiarities.

Comment: Thanks, the library is useful for my purpose.